# htaccess protection of directory does not work any longer?

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4, file-permissions

unfortunately the protection of my wp-login.php does not work any longer:

```
<Files wp-login.php>
AuthName "Forbidden access"
Require ip 1xx.xxx.xx.x/24
</Files>
```

This is apache's information:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Aug 28 2015 16:28:08
```

Error-logs are not showing anything :-(

Comment: Wnhat changes have been made to the system ?

Comment: Are you sure your ip mask is correct ? Why are you using Authname ?

Comment: Well, the system updated to Debian 8 (and Apache 2.4). No other changes. I was using AuthName because before I tried to use require ip I tried to include a .htpasswd file.

Answer (score 2):

#### Apache Basic Auth

If you want to add authentication :

```
<Location ~ "wp-login.php">
    AuthName "Auth Name You Want"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /opt/web/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

or

```
<Files "wp-login.php">
    AuthName "Auth Name You Want"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /opt/web/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Files>
```

sources : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html

#### Apache IP restriction

If you want to allow only one ip

```
<Location ~ "wp-login.php">
    Require ip w.x.y.z
</Location>
```

or

```
<Files "wp-login.php">
    Require ip w.x.y.z
</Files>
```

sources : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/howto/access.html

#### About Apache 2.4

For information this syntax is no more used on apache 2.4

```
order allow,deny
allow from all
```

It has been replaced by

```
Require all granted
```

Sources : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/howto/access.html

#### In your case

If you Want to add authentication + ip restriction in .htaccess

```
<Files "wp-login.php">
    <RequireAll>
        AuthName "Auth Name You Want"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /opt/web/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
        Require ip w.x.y.z/24
   </RequireAll>
</Files>
```

I am considering your IP mask is correct

Informations about `RequireAll` : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireall

Comment: Hello, well, I thought Location-Tag would not be possible in .htaccess? 

I'm getting this error: .htaccess: <Location not allowed here

Comment: I updated the answer for .htaccess

Comment: Thanks a lot... It's somehow "funny". There is no effect. I can directly open wp-login.php without any problems from any IP.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem with apache 2.4 and my solutions was like this :

```
<Files wp-login.php>
    AuthName "Forbidden access"
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
Allow from 1xx.xxx.xx.x/24
Deny from all
```

Comment: But this would only allow access to the rest of the wordpress-page to 1xx.xxx.xx.x/24, not only securing wp-login.php or am I wrong?

Comment: All your wordpress will continue to work and the whole world will access it normally. wp-login.php will be accessed by your local network 1xx.xxx.xx.x/24